# Load Sails programmatically and work with models

Tags: sails.js

I see that I can access models at `sails.models` after loading sails programmatically, but I can't figure out how to find and update models. I want to do something like this, is it possible?

```
const Sails = require('sails').constructor;
const sails = new Sails();
await sails.load();
const user = await sails.models.user.findOne({id:1});
```

I get an error that `findOne` does not exist. No methods exists on the models from `sails.models`, only the `customToJSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was wrong, this is the right way:

```
const Sails = require('sails').constructor;
const sails = new Sails();

sails.load({}, async () => {
  //console.log(sails.models.user);
  const u = await sails.models.user.findOne({id: 7});
  console.log(u);

  sails.lower( (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log("Error occurred lowering Sails app: ", err);
      }
      console.log("Sails app lowered successfully!");
    }
  );
});
```